# Forcing eager-loading for a navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, eager-loading

I'm using EF Code First and I have a navigation property called Category that I want eager loaded in every call:

```
public class Product
{
    ...
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

To do this I have to include it in every call I'll do on Product

```
var results = from p in db.Products.Include("Category") select p;
```

Is there a way to have Category property eager loaded, therefore generation a SQL join, in every call without having to include it every time?

thank you

Comment: Are you looking to disable lazy loading for the entire context or just these specific entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use helper method as proposed by @jeroenh but it will not solve situation where you for example want to load order with all ordered products and their categories. EF doesn't have any automatic eager loading configuration as for example available in Linq-to-sql. You must always use `Include` (either directly or by some helper construction).

Answer (score 3):

One simple way would be to define an extension method

```
static class DbExtensions{
   public IQueryable<Product> ProductsWithCategories(this MyContext db) {
       return db.Products.Include("Category");
   }
}
```

Which allows you to use

```
var results = from p in db.ProductsWithCategories() select p;
```

Not sure if it brings much benefit though...

Comment: I though about that but I wondered if there was a standard way, through data annotations of fluent API, to always eager-load :)